# How do I store multiple values in an array in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

For this example I have an array:

```
String[] books = new String[x];
```

I would like to store the id and title in each location:

```
books[0]=>id:0, title:"book title1"
books[0]=>id:1, title:"book title2"
books[0]=>id:2, title:"book title3"
books[0]=>id:3, title:"book title4"
```

I want to store the id since it may change. I'm getting the id and title from a database. Getting the info isn't the issue. I want to store it this way so in my other functions this returns to I can use something like:

```
btn.setText(regions[i].title)
```

Any suggestion on how to handle this would be great.

Comment: Why don't you create a `Book` class, that has `id` and `title` as class members?

Comment: you can use a hash map where id is the key

Comment: Use can use an `ArrayList` of `Pair<Integer,String>` objects..

Comment: you would want to brush through OOP concepts AND Collections and figure out an approach for it is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have several options

- Use a `HashMap` where you can use your `id` as key and value `title`
- Define a class and keep `id` and `title` as `attributes` , define `get and set methods`.

Keep the `objects` of the class in a `ArrayList`

Answer (score 3):

Do one thing, first create a bean class like BookBean.
Under this declare two variables ID and Title. and declare getters and setters (If u are using eclipse u can easily do this by (Source -> generate getters and setters.. option)
and then declare a ArrayList to store BookBean vale as of follow.

```
 ArrayList<BookBean> bookArrayList=new ArrayList<BookBean>();

   for(int i=0;i<=urSize;i++)
   {
    // create a object for BookBean 
    BookBean book =new BookBean();
    book.setID("what ever");
    book.setTitle("what ever");
    bookArrayList.ass(book)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use **Arraylist** with custom class.

see this

```
class Book
{
   String id,title;

   /* Cunstructor to store data */
   public Book(String id,String title) 
   {
       this.id = id;
       this.title = title;
   }
}

//declare arraylist
ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
bookList.add("1","book1");
bookList.add("2","book2");
bookList.add("3","book3");
bookList.add("4","book4");

btn.setText(bookList.get(i).title)
```

Comment: you meant: `bookList.add(new Book("1","book1"));`